# use ug with soplex to solve LP problems

Tags: scip

I think the ug use scip to solve ILP problems. But I want to solve LP problems with ug and can not find the parameters to configure ug to solve with soplex.

Is it possible to do so, or the LP solver is scalable enough and does not the trouble?

Answer (score 2):

[UG](http://ug.zib.de) is a framework for parallelizing the tree search. While there are some tricks to speed up the root as well (racing stage), it's best suited for MIP instances that require a lot of branch and bound nodes.

If you want to solve an LP in parallel, I suggest you try an interior point, aka barrier solver, as is implemented in CPLEX, Gurobi or Xpress. [SoPex](http://soplex.zib.de) is a sequential simplex solver.